# How to split the string in java by \?

Tags: java, split, special-characters

I would like to split the special character "\". 
However, it doesn't seem to work out using

```
a.split("\");
```

or

```
a.split("\\");
```

Comment: It should work: `String[] split = a.split("\\");`

Comment: Why do you think the second option won't work? Can you share an example input and explain how the result differs from what you'd expect?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\

Comment: You need **4** ``\`` to make it work. Java literal will change `"\\\\"` into the string ``\\``. Regex will make that match ``\``.

Comment: @Andreas thanks mate. make yours into an answer for the next readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could escape the *regular expression* to `String.split` with the somewhat surprising

```
String str = "a\\b\\c";
str.split("\\\\");
```

it is also possible to compile a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with [`Pattern.LITERAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL) and then use [`Pattern.split(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split-java.lang.CharSequence-) like

```
String str = "a\\b\\c";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\", Pattern.LITERAL);
String[] arr = p.split(str);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Which outputs

```
[a, b, c]
```

Comment: This is also a nice way to do it. thank you for the answer

Comment: Thanks @ChitKhine for the edit - I further changed the backticks to double-quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is solved by using

```
a.split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simply use \n inside the string where need. No method need to split.

1. "\" special character in java. It is use to skip a character. Such as String s = "I am a \"Student\" of a University!";
   Hear Double cote is not allow without using "\".
2. We can not use "\" single in a string. 
   String s = "I am a \ Student of a University!";
   Hear "\" will make an Err.
3. No method need to split using "\" Simply use "\n" Where you Need.

   ## Or use another character with it like this

   ```
   String s = "Thir is a Tiger.\'I like it very nuch!\'I it a pet!";
   String s2[] = s.split("\'");
   for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(i+" value "+s2[i]);
   }
   ```

Comment: my purpose here is to use for my file directory. When i retrieved the file directory i got the string as light\hello\text.txt. In that case, we will be having \ in the String.

Comment: Then use it.=>String s = "light\\hello\\text.txt";
        String s2[] = s.split("\\\\");
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+" value "+s2[i]);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s = "light\\hello\\text.txt";
    String s3[] = s.split(Pattern.quote("\\"));
    for (int i = 0; i < s3.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+" value "+s3[i]);
}
```